# Would C compiler always add Sentinel value 0 at the end of an array?

Tags: arrays, c

Would a sentinel value be added at the end for an array of `int` elements

```
int grades[5] = {78, 76, 75, 71, 88};
```

If the answer to the above is, "Yes," then would the sentinel value always be added, even though the last two elements have already been set to 0 as default (e.g., the code below)?

```
int grades[5] = {78, 76, 75, 0,};
```

Comment: There is no sentinel value.

Comment: `int grades[5]` always has 5 elements (regardless of their content). The compiler does not add elements for sentinel or any other value.

Answer (score 6):

The only time a compiler will add a 'sentinel' zero element is when initializing a character array with a string literal … and only then if there is sufficient space in the array.

For example, the following line will initialize an array of **four** characters, adding the `'\0'` character as the last element (because the size of the array is determined by the specified initializer list:

```c
char str[] = "abc"; // 4 chars, including nul terminator
```

However, if the size is explicitly given, that final `nul` character will only be added if the array is large enough:

```c
char s1[4] = "abc"; // s1 will be a nul-terminated string
char s2[3] = "abc"; // s2 is an array of 3 chars WITHOUT a nul-terminator
```

For all other array types, if the number of elements specified in an initializer list is *less than* the declared array size, then **all** elements beyond the last element of the initializer list will be initialized to zero:

```c
int arr[5] = {0, 1, 2}; // arr[3] and arr[4] will be initialized to zero
```

The C language does not have the concept of a true "sentinel" to mark the end of arrays; however, when using character arrays (a.k.a. C Strings), the practice (or rule) is to mark the end of the string with a zero (`nul`) character – and all standard library functions that take string arguments expect that rule to be followed (and rely on it).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your quick and thorough answer. This is my first time asking a question here. Really inspiring to see a good answer quickly.

Comment: _The only time_?   With `char *s = "abc";` a _null character_ is appended after the `c` to the _string literal_, which is an  array.

Comment: With `main()`,s, `argv[]`, the last element is a `NULL`.

Comment: @chux But, in those cases, no element is being added to an array by the compiler. In the `argv` case, it's being done by the OS (or Standard library?) and in the case of a pointer to a string literal, that literal already has the nul terminator.

Comment: @chux OK, maybe there's an argument for the string literal pointer: *In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.) The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence.*

Comment: Not just char, but other character types as well, such as wchar_t, char16_t and char32_t (char8_t when that is added to the language).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Good point. I have edited to use the more general term, "character array".